# Passing bearer token in RSPEC (no implicit conversion of nil into String)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe "User management", :type => :request do
    describe "Example::V2::Users" do
        describe "GET /api/v2/users/" do

          it 'returns status 200, authorized' do
              @token =  "Bearer 123"
              @url = "https://api.example-v2.com/v2/users/me"
              @headers = { "AUTHORIZATION" => @token}
              get @url, as: :json, headers: {:Authorization => @token}
              expect(response.status).to eq 200
          end
        end
    end
end
```

I am trying to pass the `@token` but I am getting this error

```
 Failure/Error: get @url, as: :json, headers: {:Authorization => @token}

     TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

I can make a get request without the params and headers and it works but as soon as I add params or headers I get the error, I even tried writing it like so

```
1 - get @url, {}, { Authorization:  @token} 
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)

2 - get @url, params: {}, headers: { Authorization:  @token}
TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

Some smart people please point me in the right direction =).

Gems:

```
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.8'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.2.2'
```

Comment: What version of rails and rspec do you have?

Comment: Is this a :controller test or :request test?

Comment: @TimurNugmanov Ive updated the question with the info

Answer (score 1):

```rb
get @url, as: :json, headers: { Authorization: @token }
```

this works in my environment when `type: reuqst`.
I suggest you can use `byebug` just before the GET request
and check the @token and the @url.

If everything looks good.
Check the `get` if it can make request to root url?
Check the `rails_helper` if it requires any suspicious file?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this its working for me.

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe "User management", :type => :request do
  describe "PeopleGoal::V2::Users" do
    describe "GET /api/v2/users/" do
      it 'returns status 200, authorized' do
        request.headers["AUTHORIZATION"] = "Basic #{user.id}"
        @url = "https://api.peoplegoal-v2.com/v2/users/me"
        get @url, format: :json
        expect(response.status).to eq 200
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.